# Will WP8 support MAPI

Tags: mapi, windows-phone-8

I know that the official sdk for WP8 is not yet published, but does anyone know if extended MAPI will be supported on the WP8 platform? I've used it to read SMS-folders on WM5-WM6.X and would like to give WP8 a try if I can port my old c++ code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not supported, and you'll never have a API allow you access to the users messages on Windows Phone.